# Custom HTTP headers with XmlRpcClient And Read response header

Tags: java, apache, http-headers, xml-rpc, xmlrpcclient

I was wondering if anyone knows how to send custom HTTP headers using an XmlRpcClient in Java?

I see a custom header can be set using XmlRpcHttpTransport.setRequestHeader() but I don't see a way of tying this in with the XmlRpcClient itself.And I want to know how read response header. I use apache xmlrpc.Can you give me a demo. Thanks. My email :seraphyong@126.com